# Applescript Droplet Text as Input

Tags: applescript

How can I create a droplet that takes a text selection as input? When I create a script that starts with `on run inputText`, the resulting application icon will only darken when files are dragged over it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this may require wrapping the AppleScript in a Cocoa application which feeds it the text. This seems absurdly complicated for something extremely simple. I don't know any Objective-C, so any help with how this wrapper might be created would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I could tell, this could only be achieved by wrapping the Applescript in a Cocoa application. I don't know Objective-C, but was able to cobble something together. When I get a chance I'll try to clean up a bit and post an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar result by using Automator to [make a service](http://gigaom.com/apple/quick-tip-automator-and-services-in-snow-leopard/). Services can be fed selected text, (or urls or files etc) and not just from Finder, but from the right-click contextual menu or the Services menu. You can run applescript inside the Automator script, so basically Automator makes a wrapper for your appleScript. The downside is that it tends to be even slower than applescript.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I cannot have a service run from an icon. Is there any way to run from an icon?

Answer (score 1):

Dropplets in AppleScript only support files. You can follow @stib's suggestion of using a service with Automator or using the Scripts menu (launch AppleScript Editor and choose AppleScript Editor>Preferences from the menu bar, General in the preferences window and check "Show Script menu in menu bar"). You can then place the script in the /Library/Scripts/ or ~/Library/Scripts folder to have the script appear in the menu. Alternatively, check out [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to include the ability to assign keyboard shortcuts to the scripts and enhanced menu organization.

Answer (score -1):

In applescript, you can create a simple droplet like this:

```
on open theThing
    set fileToRead to open for access theThing --open the file so we can perform operations on it
    set myVar to (read fileToRead) --The myVar variable is set to the contents of the dropped file
    display dialog myVar --Shows the contents of the file in a dialog; do what you want with the text here
    //other code here
    close access fileToRead 
end open
```

So, it's not too hard, just make sure you open for access the file first. I hope this helped!

Helpful Links:

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24772: About Droplets

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24745: About File IO

Comment: This would be a droplet that works for files. I need one for text. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In that case, and automator service would be the best way to go, or the cocoa wrapper. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.